# How to typecast?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have used the below function

```
while(labelZ.text!=0)
```

but I'm getting a typecast error.

Answer (score 4):

To check if a string is not set, use:

```
labelZ.text == nil
```

To check if a string is an empty string, use:

```
[labelZ.text isEqualToString:@""]
```

To check if a string equals "0", use:

```
[labelZ.text isEqualToString:@"0"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `nil` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while((int)labelZ.text!=0)
```